# Intuitive machines IM-1 ("Odysseus") lunar lander: commercial sponsorship

Tags: the-moon, lunar-landing, lander

Photographs including https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/24/Intuitive_Machines%E2%80%99_Nova-C_lunar_lander_%28IM_00309%29_%28cropped%29.jpg appear to show this bearing a Sun Microsystems logo. Does this mean that Oracle is trying to grab a slice of the Moon?

Comment: Looks more like the Columbia logo to me https://www.columbiasportswear.co.uk. Why would a company that's been defunct for 14 years sponsor a lunar lander?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I agree, I was wrong. However since other people might be struck by the similarity- particularly if, like me, they are non-Americans and first see the photo on e.g. the BBC, I've left the question intact and added a separate answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a little more nuanced than just an ad. Columbia Sportswear provided some thermal insulation for the vehicle.

Here is a [Columbia Sportswear ad](https://www.columbia.com/omni-heat-infinity/moon-mission/) about their contributions to the mission (link to ad is relevant to the question).

(I saw the logo a couple of days ago and asked a former colleague who works on the mission; he pointed me to the ad).

Keep in mind these commercial lander companies are [all in financial trouble](https://arstechnica.com/space/2024/02/as-companies-shoot-at-the-moon-nasas-tolerance-of-failure-is-tested/); every little bit helps.

Answer (score 5):

No. Despite distinct similarities, that turns out to be Columbia Sportswear's logo. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbia_Sportswear

So the panel shown bears two company names (Intuitive and Columbia), not two names plus another company's logo.

Apologies for generating noise, but once the question had been asked I thought it should probably be answered in a correct manner rather than being deleted.

Comment: Given the answer now exists it might be worth adding the other sponsors that have branding on the vehicle itself and description of where they stuck the logo if you can find them. Always amusing where these things end up. Just try to structure it so it does not give the appearance that you are shilling the brands themselves (eg no links).

Comment: @GremlinWranger I'll try to work through published photos etc. My apologies for starting off with the wrong assumption, which was that Columbia University and an Oracle (nee Sun) computing installation was involved.

Comment: Hey it would have been a cool find if Sun had a spacecraft sponsership!

Comment: @GremlinWranger More bragging rights to Larry Ellison: solar sail race round the Moon?

Comment: Behind Jeff Koons we can see the logo clearly https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/65232325#65232325